# EXCEL PERCENTILE result is wrong compared to a textbook?

Tags: excel

I am helping my son with his math homework, specifically statistics and this is the dataset:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I have 10 numbers from 1 to 10.

15 percentile:
in Excel I use the PERCENTILE or PERCENTILE.INC function with .15 and the result is 2.35, why?
The book way. .15*10 = 1.5 th number. There is not 1.5 number so round up to 2 or 2.

20 percentile:
In excel I get 2.8.
Book version: .2*10 = 2 (exact) so take average of 2nd and 3rd value for 2.5

50 percentile or median:
In excel I get 5.5.
Book version .5*10 = 5 (exact) so take average of 5th and 6th value for 5.5 (only match)

75 percentile 7.75:
Book, .75*10 * 7.5 so round up to 8.
Excel

80 percentile:
Excel I get 8.2
Book, .8*10*8, average of 8 and 9 is 8.5.

Obviously Excel is doing more advanced math and additional smoothing, however I have not been able to find the exact math it uses replicate it, hence I will say it is wrong. Other programs and statistical packages match Excel so it is correct, but not useful as I need it.

How can I get Excel to give me the Book version of answers or at least replicate the Excel answers with paper and a basic calculator.

Most importantly I need to find a way to explain to my son that it is OK that the results don't match that he should do it the book way, at least for now or in school.

EDIT: After posting, SO found and similar question: [Different results for percentiles in SAS and Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089046/different-results-for-percentiles-in-sas-and-excel) It seems SAS gives the same results as the book version. The answer there is that Excel and most packages use different interpolation methods. However I need a better explanation for my son and maybe a way to create a proper percentile function for my son, but hopefully without VBA.

Comment: there are different methods to come up with the percentile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile  The book and Excel are using different methods.

Comment: Excel is taking the range of 1 to 10 as 9 wide. You're taking it as 10 wide. Add 0 to your excel work and it will do what you expect.

Comment: Also, look at the Excel functions `PERCENTILE.INC` and `PERCENTILE.EXC`

Comment: Thanks, Book uses nearest-rank method, while Excel uses some interpolation, still not sure exactly which one. I am surprised that Excel does not have a flag or option for the nearest-rank version.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4794-excel-rank-percentile.html#:~:text=percentile%20in%20Excel-,Calculate%20rank%20percentile%20in%20Excel,to%20calculate%20all%20rank%20percentiles.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-percentrank-function

Comment: https://www.xelplus.com/percentile-rank-calculation-excel/